# How to verify identity on server when using an external login

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, authentication, authorization

I have to explain the scenario here: We want a single authentication authority for our WebApps. This will sit on server `A` (for Auth). This one holds the user's emails, passwords, etc. This stuff should not be shared.

Then we have server `B`, on which the App is hosted. I was able to write JavaScript for the authentication and login part, it basically works like this:

```
B loads login dialog code from A
User logs into the dialog
A now has a session (cookie) with the user
B asks the JavaScript of A for user details
```

In the browser, `B` can get the currently logged in user from `A` because the server code of `A` has access to the session, so an AJAX call works and you can be confident it does deliver.

Now, the App on `B` needs to load some privileged data from its own database, which should only be visible to the right user. So far, only the browser has knowledge if the user is logged in at all, and which is.

So just sending the user ID via AJAX to the server of `B` is ludicrously unsafe and easily faked. But since the session, cookie and user data is only ever known to `A`, `B` needs to have a way to actually verify if the access to privileged data is actually legit.

And there I'm a bit stumped in how I can design the API on `A` to support a Server-to-Server verification to ensure that `B` can check that it's the right user and that it has the right to access the data.

Maybe it's a trivial solution, but I am open for input.

Comment: Looks like user works with B and B sends AJAX requests to A? How does A set cookie in this case?

Comment: @Phantom Using CORS, also the AJAX requests go to `A`, `A` sets the cookie in the response, and the cookie is bound to the domain of `A` in the browser.

Comment: why can't A talk to B behind the scenes to turn sessionIDs into userIds?

Comment: @dandavis Because the session is not known to `B`. It's only ever known to `A`. The JavaScript could *tell* `B` about the session, but that is run in the client and easily manipulated.

Comment: @LambdaDusk: no, i mean have A ping B directly, soemthing like "34g3hj4g3j=fsmith91"... then, when js sends {value: 123, session: "34g3hj4g3j"} to B, it saves it for the user account named "fsmith91"...

Comment: @dandavis How does that differ from just sending the user ID around?

Comment: @LambdaDusk: in that you are using the temp and random session token to authenticate B instead of a permanent and guessable userID. you can expire/renew the session on each transaction if you prefer, but if you use https, i wouldn't think going to that extreme would be needed.

Comment: @dandavis Perhaps you can make the idea with the temporary session ID an answer for checking it?